# Can I use "something of something of something"?

Tags: repetition

Continuously using two of, like:

> A fragment of a wheel of the car
> A method of study of that student

Does this make any sense? Or does this look and sound bizarre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prefer to use *compound nouns* or *possessives* to avoid repetition where possible, but where it's not possible, yes, it's fine to use repeated "of".

Your examples aren't natural, and should read:

> A fragment of a wheel *from* the car
> That student's study method

It's difficult to find a natural example of repeated "of", but here's one from the title of a comedy album:

> "The Pick Of The Best Of Some Recently Repeated Python Hits Again Vol. II"

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I'm puzzled why you think "from the car" is more natural than "of the car", cf. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wheel+from+the+car%2Cwheel+of+the+car&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwheel%20from%20the%20car%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwheel%20of%20the%20car%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @stangdon I guess it doesn't mean "from the car" is more natural than "of". It's just "from the car" also works and it can avoid using "of" twice. Just my assumption.

Comment: @stangdon I picture a fragment of a wheel as not on the car anymore, so it's *from* the car. If it were, "*I could only see a **portion** of the wheel of the car*", then yes, "of" is better.